# sklearn random forest Machine learning

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, test-data

I want to output the prediction values of the random forest results from my test data into Excel and generate a map, but I need to know which line this result is for and use its coordinates, that is, how can I see the index of that test data along with the prediction?(with sklearn)

`y_pred=regr.predict(X_test) print(mean_squared_error(y_test,y_pred)) np.savetxt("y_pred.csv",y_pred)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas to create a dataframe containing X_test and y_pred and save that.

```
import pandas as pd
test=pd.DataFrame(np.c_[X_test,y_pred])
test.to_csv('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much
How to know the place of each test data in the whole data?
Because we have a coordinate for each of the data and the index of the test data must be known

Comment: if you have the coordinates of the data points in a list like the X and y data, and they have the same index, you just add them to the DataFrame. So maybe create the DataFrame first before you do the train/test split.